# How to prevent em font-sizes in a DIV from being over-ridden by main css font size

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have included a widget onto my page and wrapped it in a `div` with class `widgetText`. And all the font sizes of this widget is set in `em`s. These font sizes look OK with the `font-size` declared in widget's main css file's `body`. But when I inclde this widget into my own page, it's font sizes look way too small and are being affected by the `body` `font-size` declared on my page's css stylesheet. How do I prevent this div with class `widgetText` from being affected by main stylesheet's font-size?

Answer (score 0):

em is relative to the parent so please try to set a base size in px to widgetText.

Answer (score -1):

add !important after your em size.

e.g.

```
.widgetText{
    font-size: 12em !important;
}
```